# White openings for counter-attacking players

Tags: opening

I would like to get suggestions of openings for white that suits a counter-attacking player. As black I really enjoy playing the alekhine and the modern. As white, lately, I started playing 1.g3, but I'm not entirely satisfied with it, especially since I found absolutely no theory on that opening. I'd like to have suggestions of other (decent) openings I could play as white that would suit my counter-attacking style.

Thanks!

Comment: By "counter-attacking" do you literally mean "wait until I am attacked and then retaliate" or do you mean "aggressive"?

Comment: Why don't you attack on first place, as you are playing with Whites? :)

Comment: Try searching very agressive openings.

Comment: I suggest you just attack but don't forget to defend too. Don't play at counter I suggest.

Comment: Counter-attack means retaliation. I prefer it to simply attacking, since the opponent usually leaves holes in is defence in order to carry an unsuccessful attack. It is also a great psychological tool!

Comment: Couldn't you play 1.a3 and pretend you're Black? Or how about 1.c3 any 2.c4? OK, we need something else against 1...b5. And 1.d3 any 2.d4 might not be so good if Black plays 1...c5.

Comment: Your ideas are interesting, but altough I feel more comfortable just playing as black, I'm not ready to waste a tempo and play something like 1.d3 2.d4. I think that 1.a3 would be better, since it remains a very useful move that I usually end up playing on moves 4,5,6 or 7. It suits well the idea of later pushing b4 and mabe putting the black bishop on b2. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Wargzel There is a Chessbase DVD by Nigel Davies which you might find interesting. It is called 'Bamboozle your opponents with 1.g3'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might call the Reti a counter attacking opening for white.
White allows black to grab some space with a big centre and then tries to tear it down.

```
[FEN ""]

1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 d4 3. g3 Nc6 4. Bg2 e5
```

There also should be quite a lot of theoretical information about it. The main problem might be that black isn't easily goaded into overextending. Most players like to play it safe with black, making a counter attacking game with white less likely.

Comment: Only thing is I think a lot of people would take the free white pawn at c4 too or am I wrong?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker: if white wants he can always get it back with Qa4+, or by attacking it by moving the e-pawn or playing Na3, or he could turn this into a gambit. It would cost a lot of time for black to try to hold on to the pawn, probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Basically, it's another way of getting into an english opening and perhaps pushing black into a different system he would use against 1.c4.

Comment: Normally Nf3 is replied with another hypermodern move

Answer (score 2):

The Word Counter Attacking suits more for Black . If you read ever a Chess Book or Video the Counter Attacking is in a wrong context for White . The Player who plays White should be the Attacking one . Counterattacking goes for Black.

As for g3 opening it is Hungarian Opening . You can convert the opening to d4 Catalan/Reti which is a good repertoire for the White Player .

Answer (score 1):

Larsen's opening b3.  aims and counterattacking the center and aiming that bishop at the opponents kingside.  Bird's opening 1.f4 is basically a reverse Dutch.  You can play a reverse Alekhine's beginning with 1.g3 e5 2.Nf3 and in other lines play a reverse Modern/Pirc.

Answer (score 1):

Find lines similar to your black openings. For example, a French player might play 1. e3.

However, I don't see the point in throwing away white's advantage so early in a game.